# Populate List inside List With Conditionals Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm trying to populate a `List<Object>` that has as a attribute another `List`.

Here is The Scenario.

First Object

```
public class Student {

    private String initials;
    private String id;
    private List<StudentDetail> listStudentDetail;

    //Setters and Getters

}
```

Second Object

```
public class StudentDetail {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    //Setters and getters
}
```

My final java object is as follows.

```
public class Response {

    private String code;
    private String message;
    private List<Student> listStudent;

    //Setters and getters
}
```

I get populated a `List<Student>`and a `List<StudentDetail>` from another process and what I want to achive is merge both list into my `Response` class but with theese particular conditions

In order to fill `List<StudentDetail>`

- Student.initials must be "a"
- Student.id = StudentDetail.id

These is what I want to Achieve.

```
{
  "code": "0",
  "message": "Succes",
  "listStudent": [
    {
      "initials": "a",
      "id": "104",
      "listStudentDetail": [
        {
          "id": "104",
          "name": "Kevin"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "initials": "b",
      "id": "100",
      "listStudentDetail": []
    },
    {
      "initials": "a",
      "id": "105",
      "listStudentDetail": [
        {
          "id": "105",
          "name": "Robert"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use a Map<String, Studen> where the key is the student ID. Then loop through the details list and find the corresponding student in the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code.
I am assuming `populatedStudentList` and `populatedStudentDetail` as the given objects that have been populated in some other part of the code like you mentioned.

```
for (Student s in populatedStudentList){
    if (s.getInitials().compareTo('a') != 0){
        continue;
    }
    String findId = s.getId();
    List<StudentDetail> tempListStudentDetail = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (StudentDetail d in populatedStudentDetail){
        if (d.getId().compareTo(findId) == 0){
             tempListStudentDetail.append(d);
        }
    }
    s.setListStudentDetail(tempListStudentDetail);
}
```

This can be achieved in a more memory efficient manner using hashTables but I have tried to reproduce the desired result in the most basic manner.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with java 8 Stream and filter instead of hashTables or Map

Comment: The current solution does not use maps, I indicated that a more memory effective solution can be achieved using hashing. Also, filters could be used too, however I'm not completely convinced if they would be memory effective.